# Take picture of me using laptop camera

Tags: camera

How do I take a picture of myself using my Toshiba laptop and Windows 7? I want to save the picture and email it. I have tried looking under Toshiba > Utilities but do not find a camera option.

Comment: Depending on what is installed on the laptop its hard to say, how about installing Skype which lets you access your webcam? Plenty of other tools as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an online service like [TestMyCam](http://www.testmycam.net/)

- free, no registration required
- allows to take pictures
- download the picture as JPG
- has some effects